# Why Are Cookies Seem to Be Persisting with Date in the Past?

Tags: cookies

When I open up Developer Tools in Chrome, I see cookies that expire in 1969.  Shouldn't the browser delete them?  I thought the way to delete a cookie was to set the expiration date to a date in the past?

[image: Cookies with expiration dates in the past]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but after talking this over with a coworker, this is what I think is happening:

Unix keeps track of time using the number of seconds passed since 1 January 1970.  This number is stored as a signed 32-bit binary integer.  (On a side note, this means that [Unix will run out of time in 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), but I digress...)

Since [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) was started on January, 1 1970, -1 is in December 31, 1969, 11:59:59pm. Apparently, -1 is a commonly used value for "unknown" if the expected value is usually positive.  Cookies which have a negative MaxAge means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits.